# ElasticSearch, DELETE documents by exact match (5.1)

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to delete information that match exactly the word of the keys in the query of elastic-search, but I have problems with the request and I deleted information with the same prefix. What I have to do to fix my script and delete only the correct ones? **(Exact Match on two conditions)**

```
curl -X POST elasticDomain/index/_delete_by_query -d '{"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "component.name": {
          "query" : "prefix-component-one"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "enviroment": "qa"
      }
    }
  ]
}}}'
```

Data example, when I want to delete only information about component-one:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "event",
        "_id": "c04b0f94-4995-11e8-a9f5-a22f517abdda",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "component": {
            "name": "prefix-component-two",
            "qualifier": "TRK"
          },

          "enviroment": "history",
          "timestamp": "2018-04-26T16:06:54.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "event",
        "_id": "bf80d63e-4995-11e8-a9f5-a22f517abdda",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "component": {
            "name": "prefix-component-one",
            "qualifier": "TRK"
          },

          "enviroment": "qa",
          "timestamp": "2018-04-26T16:06:54.000Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `term` instead of `match_phrase`?

Comment: First things first: always start with a `_search` instead of delete to make sure your query matches what you need. Then you don't need boost here. And it also depends on the mapping you have. If you indexed `component.name` as a `text` that might not work as you expect. Sharing a full reproduction example would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with **match_phrase**

```
curl -X POST elasticDomain/index/_delete_by_query -d '{"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match_phrase": {
        "component.name": {
          "query" : "prefix-component-one"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "enviroment": "qa"
      }
    }
  ]
}}}
```